# No Data Holes in Certain Tiling Scheme Levels in Mosaic Dataset Imagery Cache

Tags: raster, imagery, digital-image-processing, tilecache, mosaic-dataset

I have a mosaic dataset containing three other mosaic datasets (one containing county imagery, one containing regional imagery, and one containing city imagery) I have them ordered by putting the county at the bottom (25 cm resolution), then regional (10 cm), then city (10 cm). County covers the same extents as the regional and city imagery, but the regional and city imagery is placed overtop the county imagery to use the better resolutions in their respective areas.

[image]

Each set of images are in their own mosaic dataset, and added each of them into a fourth master dataset. I created the overviews and tried to create the cache with a tiling scheme 1:577,791 - 1:564:

[image]

When I try and create a cache to publish online, the tile levels for 1:2,257 has a strange set of discoloured strips:
[image]

and the tiles at 1:1,128 and 1:564 are partially empty:
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?